# Adaptive Huffman (FKG) vs Huffman on averange length

Tags: encoding, huffman-code

I've tried many examples and can't understand why the seemingly correct FKG produces a higher average length than the simple huffman. Is it normal?

When building the *codes* on **aabcdad** we get:

1. Adaptive huffman: a = *0*, d = *10*, c = *111*, b = *1101*
2. Simple huffman: a = *0*, d = *10*, c = *110*, d = *111*

**Average length is calculated with this formula**:[image]
Which is basically the sum of each character's appearances multiplied with its code length (probability of appearance, a.k.a. frequency can also be used)

It is obvious that the average length for the simple coding is lower.

**The ultimate question: Is adaptive huffman coding optimal in terms of average code length?**

Example of adaptive building [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep590a/07au/lectures/lecture02small.pdf)

Example of simple building [here](http://huffman.ooz.ie/?text=aabcdad)

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer.

The average length concept, as presented above, is applied only to classical enodings.
Since Huffman (classic) is an injective homomorphism and Adaptive Huffman is not (the same symbol can be encoded in multiple ways) we can't apply this concept to compare the lengths.

Nevertheless, **Adaptive Huffman can sometimes output longer codes** and cannot theoretically be better than Huffman (classic), its greater advantage is only one pass of the data and also there's no need to store the entire tree.